# Elasticsearch java API fuzzy search with prefix_length

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I hope to perform this query using elastic search using Java API. For the fuzzy query, how do I get the "prefix_length" argument?

Query:

```
{"query":{"bool":{"should":[

    {"fuzzy":{"object.name":{"value":"appl", "max_expansions":"1", "prefix_length" : 3}}},

    {"prefix":{"object.name":"appl"}},

    {"term":{"object.name":"appl"}}

]}}}
```

Java API:

```
QueryBuilder result = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1)
            .should(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery(Company.FIELD_NAME, query)) ...
```

The documentation [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/query-dsl-queries/) doesn't explain how to get the "prefix_length" argument. Can someone explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha. Can add like this:

```
should(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery(Company.FIELD_NAME, query).maxExpansions(1).prefixLength(query.length() - 1)
```